# Stick NavBar on top when scroll over another div (ie. top:100vh)

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

Lets see if I can explain.
I would like a **position fixed of a navbar in the position top:100vh**, so when I scroll down and I enter in my next div the navbar stick in the top, instead of being stuck at the begining with position:fixed top:0. I want to stick it in the top at the position 100vh - 110vh.

Here is a paint image to explain better. Supposedly I only can see 100vh so when i Scroll i go to the 100vh - 200vh.. etc

[image: My Awesome drawing]

Apart from this, I'd like to have the **active class on the navbar when I am at a certain section of the page**. ex. If I am hovering on the **About** section I would like the about link of the navbar have the "*active*" class.

I hope you can understand me and I made it clear. Sorry if I am very confusing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 100vh is not the same as 100%. The latter is 100% of the height of the parent.

Comment: @Gerard wow, didnt know! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the navbar you want to be at the bottom of the page is set to `position: absolute;` and `top: 100vh;` which means, it stays there and changes it's position when you scroll.

Once you are beyond your expected scroll position, you want it to stick to the top.
So make this position set to `position: fixed;` and `top: 0;` so that it sticks to the top.

Also, just because the code snippet works, don't copy paste codes, try to understand what is actually happening here.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  if(window.scrollY > window.innerHeight){
    document.getElementById('navbar').classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('navbar').classList.remove("sticky");
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.pageOne {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: pink;
}

#navbar {
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100vh;
  left: 0;
  background: lightgreen;
  z-index: 2;
}

#navbar.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.pageTwo {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: orange;
}

.pageThree {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageOne">Div One</div>
<div id="navbar">Navbar</div>
<div class="pageTwo">Div Two</div>
<div class="pageThree">Div Three</div>
<div class="pageTwo">Div Two</div>
<div class="pageThree">Div Three</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add scroll event on page

and set navbar style  `position :static`  when page scroll top is < 100vh =  `window.innerHeight`

then check if page scroll top > 100vh

style your nav to `top :0` and `position : fixed`

add class animate for show animation

```js
window.onscroll = () => {
  let c = window.scrollY;

  if (c > window.innerHeight) {
    document.getElementById("nav").className = "fixed-nav";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nav").className = "";
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
}

nav {
  background-color: red;
}

.fixed-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:100vh"></div>
<nav id="nav" style="height:100px"></nav>
<div style="height:100vh"></div>
<div style="height:100vh"></div>
```